# maximum likelihood estimation drawing balls with replacement

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

> Let's say I have balls in an urn which are labeled with the numbers  $1 \cdots N$. I take a ball out of the urn, write down it's number and put it back. I will repeat this a total of $n$ times.
> Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $N$.

The distribution of my model is the multinomial distribution ${\mathcal{M}}_{N}(\vec{k}) =\binom{N}{\vec{k}}\prod_{i=1}^N{(\frac{1}{N})^{k_i}} $

$k_i$ is the number of times the number $i$ has been seen in the sample.

I am new to statistics and would appreciate any help in how to properly take on this question.

Comment: With the multinomial you are losing information (the information of the number). If you take only one ball and its number is "197", you know that there is at least 197 balls. I think the maximum likelihood is the maximum observed number, but I would have to think about it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you don't use the number information. Firstly, think in one extraction:
$$\mathbf{P}(X=x)=\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{1}\{1\leq x\leq N\}$$
where $\mathbf{1}\{\}$ is the indicator function (its value is 1 if its argument is true and its value is 0 if its argument is false). Then you repeat the experiment $n$ times, so the likelihood is:
$$\mathcal{L}(N|\mathbf{x})=\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^n\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}\{x_i\leq N\}=\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^n\mathbf{1}\{\max(\mathbf{x})\leq N\}$$
where $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and we asume that every $x_i\in\mathbb{N}$. The last equality is proved using indicator properties: the product of indicators is 1 iff every indicator is 1 and every $x_i\leq N$ iff $\max(\mathbf{x})\leq N$. Finally, as $\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^n$ decreasing with $N$, the maximum likelihood estimator is the minimum $N$ where the indicator function is 1. That is $\hat{N}=\max(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Could you maybe add how the model would change if we wouldn't replace the balls each time ?

Comment: It is the same. The indicator function doesn't change (if you assume that the values of $\mathbf{x}$ are different), the only change in the likelihood is to remplace $\frac{1}{N^n}$ by $\frac{1}{N!}$. Both are decreasing with $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be the numbers on the $n$-balls. Then the likelihood function (the probability of observing the data given $N$) is
$$\mathcal{L}(N; x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (1/N)^n$$
if $N \geq \max_i x_i$ and is $0$ otherwise. What value of $N$ should you choose to maximize this function?